# SelectList not returning the value of text only returns ID

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view, selectlist

I am quite new to asp net core and am trying to implement a select list while passing values from view to controller. All else is working fine only problem I am facing is only the ID is being passed to controller and not the text/name.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Below is my code.

#### View Snippet

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Financial Year</label>
    <select asp-for="FinancialYear" asp-items="ViewBag.FinancialYear" class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false" data-size="5">
    </select>
</div>
```

#### Model Snippet

```cs
public class VMOM
{ 
    public int FinancialYear { get; set; } 
}

public class VMDropDown
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller Snippet

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    VMOM vmOM = new VMOM();
    ViewBag.FinancialYear = new SelectList(GetFinancialYearList(), "ID", "Text", 0).ToList();
    return View(vmOM);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(VMOM vmOM)
{
    return View(vmOM);
}

private List<VMDropDown> GetFinancialYearList()
{
    List<VMDropDown> vmDropdowns = new List<VMDropDown>
    {
        new VMDropDown() { ID = 1, Text = "2019" },
        new VMDropDown() { ID = 2, Text = "2020" }
    };
    return vmDropdowns;
}
```

A SS of the values received in action method; note that in Financial Year only the ID of the year is being diplayed and not the text value i.e, 2020

[image: A SS of the values received in action method; note that in Financial Year only the ID of the year is being diplayed and not the text value i.e, 2020]

Comment: This is normal behaviour. The `ID` in your `select` is the option's value and when you submit a `form`, values are submitted not text. You can pass your text and id using Javascript and Ajax.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But i was able to get values when i coded in this manner for the very first time and for the first set of parameters. I also got the values in controller. But when i added the same code for other parameters and then re-run the project its behavior changed. What was that then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind a little bit of javascript you can easily achieve what you want.

We add a hidden input field where its value is updated on the `select` change.
So when we submit the form, the hidden input's value will be submitted and binded with our model (See screenshot below).

Razor:

```html
<form asp-action="Post" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.List" asp-for="@Model.Id" id="FYear">
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="FYearText" asp-for="@Model.Year" readonly="readonly" hidden/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Model

```cs
public class VMOM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var data = new List<VMOM> {
        new VMOM { Id = 1, Year = "2018" },
        new VMOM { Id = 2, Year = "2019" },
        new VMOM { Id = 3, Year = "2020" },
        new VMOM { Id = 4, Year = "2077" }
    };

    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(data, "Id", "Year");

    return View("Index", new VMOM());
}
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FYear").on("change", function(){
        $("#FYearText").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

Result:

[image]

P.S, I am using jQuery in this example for brevity.

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked for me. Although i figured it out before this reply, but for any newbie like me, this works. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is changing the ID value the same as the Text.

```
List<VMDropDown> vmDropdowns = new List<VMDropDown>
{
    new VMDropDown() { ID = 2019, Text = "2019" },
    new VMDropDown() { ID = 2020, Text = "2020" }
};
```

Comment: This works fine till the text value is in integers.. as ID won't be taking string parameters.

Comment: Also by giving string to ID, it stops taking in any values and with database it can't work i guess.. I am not sure abt the database thing though coz i am on the front end. but the IDs are default on int.

Comment: Why the ID can be string? it has been defined as int in VMDropDown.

Comment: It was not only the case for displaying "Years" for me, I had o display a number of different records as well which were not integers. So, i could not go with this approach.